# Widget content hide after drag in Widget Area wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget

When I drag my custom widget to Widget Area, its load faster and then its collapse, show only delete, done and save options. Then, I refresh page and everything is ok, its show all content. The widget content is a form. What did I miss?. This is function construct:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->arr_descriptions = array();
    parent::__construct(
    // widget ID
    'widget_vocabularies_list',
    // widget name
    __('Vocabularies List', 'widget_vocabularies_list_domain'),
    // widget description
    array( 'description' => __( 'Listado de vocabularios', widget_vocabularies_list_domain' ), )
            );
}
```